# Problem with graphic when booting from liveCD

Tags: ati, lenovo, live-cd, amd-processor

i have laptop Lenovo ideapad z50-75 AMD version and i want to install Ubuntu on my external HDD. I setup bios to legacy mode and boot from liveCD. After boot ubuntu from liveCD i should see a window, where i choose language and if i wanna try or install. But i only see black screen, only dark purple frame of this window and nothing else.

Computer spec:

- processor: AMD FX-7500 radeon R7
- graphic card: AMD R7 M260DX
- RAM: 8GB

I download Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit version. Is any solution how to repair graphic to see choices?

This is, what i see, when i do UEFI boot from liveCD and start files browser.
if i boot in legacy mode, same thing happend but with the window, where u can choose language and  try Ubuntu or Install.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried UEFI boot?

Comment: nope i will try it right now

Comment: I try UEFI boot. I was in Ubuntu, but still problem with graphic. For example if i click on file browser, it opens window and i see only purple frame and black inside

Comment: Welcome on AskUbuntu.com :-D What graphics card are you using? Please add that info to your question (edit it). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try choose language and "Try use Ubuntu without install"(or similar). Boot Ubuntu in Live mode and install Ubuntu from this mode.

Comment: That's the problem. I can't choose language if i don't see that